# Problem editing Action Script 2.0 to cycle through an image folder

Tags: image, actionscript-2, flash-cs3

I was wondering if someone can look at the ActionScript (2.0) i have from a flash menu that I bought. I know some flash but can't seem to find a way to make the images cycle through all the photos in the folder instead of loading just one random static .jpg. Also, I would like the images to load with a fade effect.

Thanks for any help!!!

The main AS

//PHOTO
photo = random(5)+1;
loadMovie("flash-header-images/"+photo+".jpg", pic.loadhere);
onEnterFrame = function () {
lefta = gotoa-_alpha;
_alpha += lefta/8;
if (loadhere._alpha>100 && _alpha>100) {
delete onEnterFrame;
}
};

The frame that the pics load

onEnterFrame = function () {
if (loadhere._height>30) {
masker.nextFrame();
} else {
masker.prevFrame();
}
};

Comment: maybe you can start with useing code tags. and i don't see how the frame loads the pics?

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to browse a folder in pure as2. 
Your XML contains path and images names, the only way to do it is to use a php (or any server side script) to browse the folder and output the results in XML.

Comment: Is there any way to change the current way it is loading one image from the folder so that it will randomly cycle through all of them?